# Very simple get request yields in error: 'Cast to ObjectId failed'

Tags: node.js, express, postman

So I was testing my backend with postman and have no clue what the heck is going on at the moment. I got a file `users.js` where I define some of my routes. I import that file into my `app.js` with:

```
// Bring in the Users route
const users = require('./routes/api/users');
app.use('/api/users', users);
```

So all the api requests within `users.js` are actually going to `/api/users/......`

I defined a simple route here to test it out.

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

router.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send('hello world')
})

module.exports = router;
```

So if I send a request with postman to: `http://localhost:5000/api/users/` I get back a response: `hello world`

If I **ONLY** change the endpoint to something like `/test`, I get an error message. In other words, If I change the route to:

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

router.get('/test', (req, res) => {
    res.send('hello world')
})

module.exports = router;
```

And again send a request with postman to `http://localhost:5000/api/users/test`, I get back the following error message:

```
{
    "stringValue": "\"test\"",
    "kind": "ObjectId",
    "value": "test",
    "path": "_id",
    "reason": {},
    "message": "Cast to ObjectId failed for value \"test\" at path \"_id\" for model \"Project\"",
    "name": "CastError"
}
```

Does anyone have a clue what is going on? I cannot see why this doesn't work...

***EDIT:***

Okay, so I figured it out, but I still don't know why it works in scenario 1 and doesn't work in scenario 2:

**This works:**

```
router.get('/test', (req, res) => {
    res.send('hello world')
})

//load project
router.get('/:id', (req, res) => {
    Project.findById(req.params.id)
        .then(projectFound => {
            res.status(200).send(projectFound)
        })
        .catch(err => {
            res.status(500).send(err)
        })
})
```

This **doesn't** work:

```
//load project
router.get('/:id', (req, res) => {
    Project.findById(req.params.id)
        .then(projectFound => {
            res.status(200).send(projectFound)
        })
        .catch(err => {
            res.status(500).send(err)
        })
})

router.get('/test', (req, res) => {
    res.send('hello world')
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Order to Precedence of Controllers

`:id` is a variable. When you declare the `router.get('/:id', (req, res)` first, your `test` method never gets executed.

This is because `:id` takes the value of test. 
And your code doesn't like the 'test' id, so you get an error.

When you declare the other method first, `router.get('/test'` is found first, and executed first for any request that is `/test`. All other requests are forwarded to the `:id` method.

### Answer to Initial Question

```
var express = require('express')
var app = express()

app.get('/test', function (req, res) {
  res.send('HELLO WORLD')
})
```

[Source](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html)

Comment: I edited my question, I now know the solution to the problem, I don't know why the solution works. Do you mind checking out the edited bit in the question and reply with an answer if you know why it works?

Comment: @Reinier68 see my order of precedence response. I have updated my answer.

Comment: I thought it was something like that, I just thought it was very strange. Took me nearly an hour to figure this out lol. Learn something everyday I guess. Ty, I accepted your answer.

Answer (score 0):

> I got a file users.js where I define some of my routes.

How are the routes defined?

Given the error message, presumably it is expecting /api/users/{id}, where {id} is a number, not a string like "test".

Comment: I edited my question, I now know the solution to the problem, I don't know why the solution works. Do you mind checking out the edited bit in the question and reply with an answer if you know why it works?